# iterating over columns to highlight the differences between two data sets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

when comparing two dfs of the same `shape`

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    # sample dataset
    df = pd.read_csv('https://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/rdataset/source/file/'
                     'master/csv/datasets/mtcars.csv')
    df.columns.values[0] = 'make'
    df[['make', 'model']] = df['make'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)

    # copy to a'new' & change a few values in 'new'
    old, new = df.copy(), df.copy()
    new.at[5, 'model'] = 'Regal'
    new.iloc[[0,1], 2] = 22

    # create boolean masks for columns and rows
    m1, m2 = new.eq(old).all(axis=1), new.eq(old).all(axis=0)

    #subsets with values that changed
    old_, new_ = old.loc[~m1,~m2], new.loc[~m1,~m2]
```

i'm trying to output a subset df with changed values by taking the differences for numeric columns and would like to show "what changed" `f'{"old"} >>>{"new"}'` element-wise for non-numeric.  The below errors out though:

```
# output 
out = new_.copy()
for col in out.select_dtypes(include=['number']):
        col.values = col.values -  old_[col.name].values

for col in out.select_dtypes(include=['object']):
        col.values = f'{col.values} -->  {old_[col.name].values}'
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you iterate over the column **names** instead of the columns themselves.

Try:

```
out = new_.copy()
for col in out.select_dtypes(include=['number']):
    out[col] = out[col] - old_[col]

for col in out.select_dtypes(include=['object']):
    out[col] = out[col].str.cat(old_[col], sep="  -->  ")
```

Use pandas.Series.str.cat in order to concatenate string values.

I think this still does not exactly do what you want, but it solves the errors.

Comment: thanks, not sure how i missed that,  must be a case of Fridays!  i got what i wanted by using another boolean mask  `m3 = out[col].ne(old_[col])`